# PlayFramework 2.2 Java Action Composition

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been using Action composition on my Play! apps until now, and they worked fine. However with the recent 2.2.0 update they no longer work and I don't know how to updated them correctly.

That this action for example:

```java
public class ChatMsgValidation extends Action<ChatMsgValidation.ValidChatMsg> {

@With(ChatMsgValidation.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidChatMsg {
}


public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

    Utils.debugFunctionCall("ValidChatMsg() " + ctx.toString());

    // validate we got the "player" parameter
    JsonNode jsonRequest = request().body().asJson();
    if (!WSUtils.validateJSONField(Constants.JSON_MSG, jsonRequest)) {
        return badRequest(WSUtils.simpleMissingFieldMsg(Constants.JSON_MSG));
    }

    RequestParser requestParser = new RequestParser(request());
    String chatMsg = requestParser.getMessage();

    if (chatMsg.isEmpty()) {
        return badRequest(WSUtils.simpleFailureMsgWithReason(Messages.get("message.cannot.be.empty.error"), FailConstants.REASON_EMPTY));
    }


    if (chatMsg.length() < Constants.MIN_CHAT_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
        return badRequest(WSUtils.simpleFailureMsgWithReason(Messages.get("query.lower.limit.error"), FailConstants.REASON_TOO_SHORT));
    }

    if (chatMsg.length() > Constants.MAX_CHAT_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
        return badRequest(WSUtils.simpleFailureMsgWithReason(Messages.get("message.too.long.error"), FailConstants.REASON_TOO_LONG));
    }

    return delegate.call(ctx);
}
}
```

Problem is now the "call" method should return "Promise" instead of "Result", and I can't figure out a way to return a simple JSON message without doing a LOT of code, useless code because I'm creating dummy functions just to have Promises. There has to be a better way I'm not seeing, please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out a better solution for my problem. It is as follows:

```
return F.Promise.pure((SimpleResult) badRequest(WSUtils.simpleFailureMsgWithReason(Messages.get("message.cannot.be.empty.error"), FailConstants.REASON_EMPTY)));
```