# How to create an Action in Play Framework 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm reading James Ward's code on how to setup some basic security for API end points using authToken (https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security).

There's a `SecurityController` class which extends `Action.Simple`. In it, there's a `call()` method that acts as proxy between the actual http call and the controllers. The problem I'm having is that apparently the return type of this method was changed in the play framework version 2.2 and now returns a `Promise<SimpleResult>` instead of a `Promise`.

This is the problematic method that does not compile since there's a Type mismatch when I try to `return unauthorized("unauthorized");`

```
public Promise<play.mvc.SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
    User user = null;
    String[] authTokenHeaderValues = ctx.request().headers().get(AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER);
    if ((authTokenHeaderValues != null) && (authTokenHeaderValues.length == 1) && (authTokenHeaderValues[0] != null)) {
        user = models.User.findByAuthToken(authTokenHeaderValues[0]);
        if (user != null) {
            ctx.args.put("user", user);
            return delegate.call(ctx);
        }
    }
    return unauthorized("unauthorized"); // type mismatch here
}
```

Any ideas how to make this code work in Play 2.2? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Play's Java API, but it looks like `unauthorized()` returns a `SimpleResult`.

You need a `Promise<SimpleResult>`, which (via the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011272/playframework-2-2-java-action-composition)) seems to be obtainable by doing:

```
return F.Promise.pure((SimpleResult) unauthorized("unauthorized"));
```

Comment: Yeah, that works great. It's sad to see just how much documentation this framework is lacking.